# Expand resultset across array values

Tags: postgresql, join, group-by

I'm running some reporting queries and I want to expand the results for each record across a specific set of 4 weeks.

This is the current query:

```sql
select
  job_id,
  week,
  count(*),
  sum(count(*)) over (partition by job_id)
from candidates
group by job_id, week
```

**Current result**:

```
 job_id | week | count | sum 
--------+------+-------+------
   3258 |    1 |    21 |  23 
   3258 |    2 |     2 |  23 
   3259 |    1 |     1 |   4 
   3259 |    4 |     1 |   4
```

But ideally, I want to expand over a specific range of 4 weeks:

**Desired Result**

```
 job_id | week | count | sum 
--------+------+-------+-----
   3258 |    1 |    21 |  23 
   3258 |    2 |     2 |  23 
   3258 |    3 |     0 |  23 # added row with 0 count
   3258 |    4 |     0 |  23 # added row with 0 count
   3259 |    1 |     1 |   4 
   3259 |    2 |     0 |   4 # added row with 0 count
   3259 |    3 |     0 |   4 # added row with 0 count
   3259 |    4 |     1 |   4
```

Using a LEFT JOIN does not return the desired result as you can see in this [SQL fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7sMPXNJt9wRNLTe64advGu/1)

**Schema (PostgreSQL v9.6)**

```
CREATE TABLE candidates(
   job_id integer,
   week integer,
   count1 integer,
   sum1 integer
);

INSERT INTO candidates(job_id, week, count1, sum1) VALUES (3984, 1, 13, 26);
INSERT INTO candidates(job_id, week, count1, sum1) VALUES (3984, 2, 13, 26);

INSERT INTO candidates(job_id, week, count1, sum1) VALUES (3985, 1, 42, 46);
INSERT INTO candidates(job_id, week, count1, sum1) VALUES (3985, 4, 3, 46);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
select
  c.job_id,
  weeks.week_nr as week,
  c.count1,
  c.sum1
from generate_series(1,4) as weeks(week_nr)
left join candidates c on c.week = weeks.week_nr 
order by c.job_id, week;
```

```
| job_id | week | count | sum |
| ------ | ---- | ----- | --- |
| 3984   | 1    | 1     | 2   |
| 3984   | 2    | 1     | 2   |
| 3985   | 1    | 1     | 2   |
| 3985   | 4    | 1     | 2   |
| null   | 3    | null  | null|
```

---

Comment: In SQLfiddle you used generate_series() and get expected result.

Comment: Use Join instead of left join then you will get without null values.

Answer (score 0):

In postgresql we can get range values used **generate_series()** (or)  **where** condition

```
 select job_id,week,count(*),sum(count(*)) over (partition by job_id)
 from generate_series(1,4) as weeks(week_nr)
 left join candidates c on c.week = weeks.week_nr 
 group by job_id, week order by job_id,week;

                       (or)

 select job_id,week,count(*),sum(count(*)) over (partition by job_id)
 from candidates where week>=1 and week<=4
 group by job_id, week;
```

Comment: Sadly, this does not yield the desired result. See the updated description.